# stop refresh of page between hours

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where I want to check the time and do something based on it. For example, from 12 midnight to 1 am, I would like to stop the page from refreshing. How would I accomplish this?

```
function RefreshPage()
{
    if (refresh == 'Y')
    {
                CheckAndStopAutoRefresh();
        }
}

function CheckAndStopAutoRefresh()
{
    var d = new Date(); 
        var currentHour = d.getHours(); // 0-23 


        if (currentHour >= 0 && currentHour < 1) 
        { 
        return;      

        }  
        else 
        { 
            window.location=window.location; // refresh
        } 


}
```

Comment: Define "stop the page from refreshing". If you want to disable the user's browser's "refresh" button then, of course, you may not.

Comment: I have a "setTimeOut" function which refreshes the page. I just need to stop the page from refreshing between those time.

Comment: You didn't mention that at all in your question. So, in fact, you want to _not_ do something "based on it".

Comment: does my answer help? post the contents of the function and I can try to help further.

Comment: @matchew -- my issue is how do i keep looping for that time period?

Answer (score 5):

```
//initialize date object
var d = new Date();
var currentHour = d.getHours(); //note 0-23

//you could use currentHour == 0 but this expression allows for a range    
if (currentHour >= 0  &&  currentHour < 1) 
 { 
     console.log('between 0:00 and 1:00 hrs');
  }
 else { console.log('after 1am'); }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date provides and overview of the date object

I am not too sure what you mean by 'stop refresh' I do not believe it possible to disable refresh/F5, but perhaps if you modify your question or specify your intentions I can take another stab at the question.

**EDITED**

--edited to reflect updated question.

I would use setInterval(code,millisec,lang)

```
function CheckAndStopAutoRefresh() {
    //initialize date object
    var d = new Date();
    var currentHour = d.getHours(); //note 0-23

    //you could use currentHour == 0 but this expression allows for a range    
    if (currentHour >= 0  &&  currentHour < 1) 
     { 
         console.log('between 0:00 and 1:00 hrs');
      }
     else { console.log('after 1am'); }
}

setInterval(CheckAndStopAutoRefresh,60000); //60,000 milliseconds in a minute
```

Comment: `if ( 0  <= currentHour <= 1) ` does not work in JavaScript.  It's interpreted as `(0 <= currentHour) <= 1` which is equal to `TRUE <= 1` which is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Rocket, it did in chromium (webkit), I will remodify my answer to what I had previously.

Comment: @matchew: I just tested it Chrome 12.0.742.91, and Firefox 4.0.1 and it doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: Also pass a function, not a string to `setInterval` Not point in having it `eval`ed.

Comment: @matchew -- can you fix what i have with what you suggested?

Comment: @Davy8, true. I shouldn't be so Sloppy. @Jack, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @matchew almost, I believe you still need to remove the `()` but +1 anyway

Comment: @Davy8, it works for me with or without the (). I decided to google it, and a lot of the documentation shows them passing the function as a string as I originally had. However, I know that does not work.

Comment: @matchew -- thanks for the help. SetInterval did it for me. I appreciate your help and everyone else who gave input.

Comment: @matchew I believe with the `()` it will execute it right away, then do nothing, because CheckAndStopAutoRefresh() doesn't return a function.  As a string it will work, however it will be `eval`ed which is less efficient and the ability to pass a string really only works because of backwards compatibility with half of the poorly written examples online.